# Add user in contact list xmpp using openfire restAPI ios

Tags: ios, xmpp, openfire

I want to add user in my contact list so i can get the presence of user.
I used this api but not getting user presence

```
http://example.org:9090/plugins/restapi/v1/users/testuser/roster
```

Comment: Can you provide more details? What is the response you receive? Do you send also the authentication, in your request?

Comment: blank page showing after hit this ,
at example.org i'm using my hostipaddress ,
and also for Authorization in header
Authorization 6N5F1gD9
Content-Type application/xml